# Routing issue: Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

My routes:

```
            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: null,
                constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" }
            );

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ApiControllerActionRoute",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                );
```

My methods:

```
// GET api/Set/All
        [ActionName("All")]
        public IEnumerable<Set> GetSets()
        {
            var sets = _repository.GetAllSets();
            return sets;
        }

        // GET api/Set/TopLevelSets
        [ActionName("TopLevelSets")]
        public IEnumerable<Set> GetTopLevelSets()
        {
            var sets = _repository.GetTopLevelSets();
            return sets.ToList();
        }

        // GET api/Set/Breadcrumbs/1
        [ActionName("Breadcrumbs")]
        public IEnumerable<Set> GetBreadCrumbs(int id)
        {
            var sets = _repository.GetBreadcrumbs(id);
            return sets.ToList();
        }

        // GET api/Set/5
        public Set GetSet(int id)
        {
            Set set = _repository.GetSet(id);
            if (set == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
            }

            return set;
        }

        // PUT api/Set/5
        public HttpResponseMessage PutSet(Set set)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }

            _repository.UpdateSet(set);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        // POST api/Set
        public HttpResponseMessage PostSet(Set set)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _repository.AddSet(set);
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, set);
                return response;
            }
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }

        // DELETE api/Set/5
        public HttpResponseMessage DeleteSet(int id)
        {         
            _repository.DeleteSet(id);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, id);
        }
```

At this point I'm trying to hit the localhost/api/set/1 - getSet method.  Everything seems to line up with the routes but it's not working for some reason.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is this pseudo code, or cut and paste?  Your GetSet Action is missing the ActionName annotation:  [ActionName("Set")], so GetSet won't match the Set route you're looking for

Comment: Cut and paste - wouldn't this hit the first route and say controller = Set and id = 1?  This was working before I added the non-standard methods and second route registration.  If I add the Action annotation then wouldn't I need to hit /api/set/set/1?

Comment: No - The action name attribute will actually replace the name GetSet with your desired name "Set". By using [ActionName("Set")] it will have the route /api (controller)/set (action) /1 (id) - match your GetSet Action.  Alternatively, you could rename your action from GetSet to Set (which may be easier to understand anyway)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't include this - my controller is named "SetController".  I'm accessing All via /api/set/all - but api/set/1 is giving me that error.  Does this make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default route isn't setting a default action, so when you use the 'Get' Action the routing engine could not decide if you wanted GetTopLevelSets or GetSet.  Adding a default will fix this:

```
 routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = "GetSet" },
                constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" }
            );
```

Would have it default to your `GetSet` Action in your controller using: `api/set (controller)/1 (id)` route.

Comment: Thank you very much.  What about my Put action, which I would like to be accessed by api/set (controller)?

Or DeleteSet > api/set/id for DELETE?

Comment: They should still work - your problem was that when you had the 'Get' Action the routing engine could not decide if you wanted GetTopLevelSets or GetSet.  Now, it will default to GetSet on a Get request (the put/post/delete will still default to their own).  You'll have to access GetTopLevelSets explicitly though.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the api portion of your query? localhost/**api**/set/1

Comment: whoops!  mistyped that bit.  I'm indeed trying /api/set/1